# Replace current table with coalesce statement

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I have a table like named innerjoined:

[image]

This current table has fields that are empty. And I have a code that removes rows with a blank value.

```
`SELECT productcode, Brand, product, size FROM innerjoined WHERE
 COALESCE(productcode, '') <> '' AND
 COALESCE(Brand, '') <> '' AND
 COALESCE(product, '') <> '' AND
 COALESCE(size, '') <> ''`
```

So it ends up just like this:

[image]

My question is:
How do I update the current table without creating a new one based on this formula?
I have tried the following:

```
`update innerjoined(SELECT productcode, Brand, product, size FROM innerjoined WHERE
COALESCE(productcode, '') <> '' AND
COALESCE(Brand, '') <> '' AND
COALESCE(product, '') <> '' AND
COALESCE(size, '') <> '')`
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I just do not understand why you are not using:

```
SELECT productcode, Brand, product, size
FROM innerjoined
WHERE productcode <> '' AND
      Brand <> '' AND
      product <> '' AND
      size <> '';
```

It is simpler and does the same thing.

Second, you appear to want `delete`:

```
delete i from innerjoined i
    where productcode = '' or productcode is null or
          brand = '' or brand is null or
          product = '' or product is null or
          size = '' or size is null;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e2a273926cb760d21331b196e11d105e) is a db<>fiddle illustrating that all of this code works, with both empty strings and NULLs.

Comment: Ho Gordon, your top code.. returns me nothing and just shows column headers, not sure why and the 2nd. error code: 1064 error at line 2

Comment: nice index friendly answer.

Comment: Its all working now, thanks for your time once again. I have deleted all values without realizing it